# From SSP={x->0,y->1} how to get SSP1={0,1} ?

Tags: differential-equations

My question is next :

```
g = -Sqrt[1 - y^2]; h = Sqrt[1 - x^2]; Vars = {x, y};

ssp1 = Solve[{g == 0, h == 0}, Vars]
```

I get this

$\{\{x\to -1,y\to -1\},\{x\to -1,y\to 1\},\{x\to 1,y\to -1\},\{x\to 1,y\to 1\}\}$

My question is how from this get SSP={{-1,-1},{-1,1},{1,-1},{1,1}} ?

I need this ,to make modification for my program PLOTING DOMAIN OF DIFFERENTIAL EQUATIONS.

Comment: And ofc , not only for 4 points , that program needs to work for 1 ,2,3 or anything ..

Comment: `ssp1 = {x, y} /. Solve[{g == 0, h == 0}, Vars]`

Comment: Or `SSP={x,y}/.ssp1` if you `Solve` first.

Comment: See [this knowledge base article](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12505)

Answer (score 2):

```
Values[ssp1]
```

> ```
> {{-1, -1}, {-1, 1}, {1, -1}, {1, 1}}
> ```